# how to get the value of a string variable in java

Tags: java, html, jsp

I send some values from one jsp page to another using link like -

```
<a href="get.jsp?value=Mobile">Mobile Phones</a>
```

In the nex page i get the value using request.getParameter like-

```
if (request.getParameter("value") == "Mobile") {
         electronicType = "Mobile Phone";
}
```

Then I want to make another link using the value like-

```
<a href="mob.jsp">electronicType</a>
```

Instead of electronicType I want the value of electronicType. But I can not get the value of electronicType. please somebody help me.

Comment: First, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Then use request attributes and EL.

Comment: reply so that v know you have got ur answer and v can close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (request.getParameter("value") == "Mobile") {
         electronicType = "Mobile Phone";
}
```

This is wrong,for comparison in java you need to use `.equals`
So your code should be

```
if (request.getParameter("value").equals("Mobile")) {
             electronicType = "Mobile Phone";
    }
```

`==` you can use for number or if you want to check if an object is null

For example `if(object == null)`

But for Strings you need to use `.equals`

Read the SO post that ***Sotirios Delimanolis*** has suggested

And in your `<a href="mob.jsp">electronicType</a>` use JSP tags like this

```
<a href="mob.jsp"><%=electronicType%></a>
```

Or a better way

```
<a href="mob.jsp"><c:out value="${electronicType}" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

AS suggested by @Sanito use equals() instead of = to comparing String

```
<a href="mob.jsp"><c:out value="${electronicType}" /></a>
```

used JSTL to print value

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that you are not comparing two strings right way. Use equals() method.

For electronicType, add a session varible for electronicType and use it whenever you need from session. Otherway is to add it in the url.